# Xamarin UITest not sending keys to Android version 10

Tags: xamarin.android

Please assist as I have an issue with xamarin UITest , the EnterText method is not sending any keys to Android version 10 devices. the Repl() shows that the text is entered but on the actual device nothing is being inserted .The code works fine on Android version 9 and below     [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qcko6.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug with xamarin ui test, see https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter/issues/1451

I implemented the following as a workaround:

```
protected bool OnAndroid => AppManager.Platform == Platform.Android;
protected bool OniOS => AppManager.Platform == Platform.iOS;

public void SetEntryText(Query entry, string entryName, string value)
{
  if (OnAndroid)
  {
    app.Query(e => e.Marked(entryName).Invoke("setText", value));
  }
  else if (OniOS)
  {
    app.ClearText(entry);
    app.EnterText(entry, value);
  }
}
```